# Extracting multiple strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract multiple parameter strings from the following kind of input:

> var paramsString = "first='somevalue' second='another value' third='another'"

With the resulting object:

```
var paramsObject = { 
    first: 'somevalue', 
    second: 'another value', 
    third: 'another' 
};
```

I initially thought I could do `paramsString.split(" ")` but then I realised (as illustrated above) that some of the values could have spaces in.

I then thought maybe a RegEx like:

```
paramsObject.first = paramsString.match("first='(.*)'")[0];
```

But that goes all the way to the last `'` character after the `third` value.

I could do this with `indexOf()` and `substring` but that seems really verbose espsecially when scaling to more parameters.

What is the most efficent and neat way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
var paramString = "first='somevalue' second='another value' third='another'"
paramString.match(/\w+='.*?'/g).reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    var parts = curr.split('=');
    prev[parts[0]] = parts[1].replace(/(^'|'$)/g, '');
    return prev;
}, {});
```

After matching with `/\w+='.*?'/g` regexp, power of [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) does the rest converting array of matches to the object.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.  You should, however, remember that you don't want to capture anything (.*) but rather anything that doesn't indicate the end of the value or '.

So something like `/\w+='([^']*)'/g` should meet your requirements (I'm assuming the key name will not involve anything complicated).  See [here](http://regexr.com/38to0) for a working example.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while loop and a regex to keep retrieving the key/values from the string and remove that part of the string each time until the regex no longer matches. Something like this should do what you're after;

```
var paramsString = "first='somevalue' second='another value' third='another'",
    paramsObject = {};

while ((matches = /^ ?([^=]+)='([^']+)' ?/.exec(paramsString))) {
    paramsString = paramsString.substr(matches[0].length);
    paramsObject[matches[1]] = matches[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function parse(str) {
    var out = {};

    str.match(/([^= ]+='[^']+')/g).forEach(function(sub){
            var m = sub.match(/([^=]+)='([^']+)/i);

            if (m.length === 3) {
                out[m[1]] = m[2];
            }
        }
    );

    return out;
}


parse("a_1='someValue' a_2='another value' a_3='another'");
```

Than you will have:

```
{
    a_1 : "someValue",
    a_2 : "another value",
    a_3 : "another"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way, using `exec` instead of `match`. The main advantage is that the object returned by `exec` already contains the mathed groups, without any further processing:

```
var paramsObject = {};
var paramsString = "first='somevalue' second='another value' third='another'";
var re = /(\w+)='([\w ]+)'/gi;

while((ma = re.exec(paramsString)) != null){
    paramsObject [ma[1]] = ma[2];
}
```

See [RegExp.exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) references at MDN for further details.